# OrmLiteBaseActivity vs. AppCompatActivity?

Tags: android, android-activity, orm, android-appcompat, ormlite

I am trying to use ORMLite in my app (because apparently writing all the CRUD methods myself is the "harder not smarter" way to develop), but I am running into a problem: A lot of the sample projects I see have Activities that extend OrmLiteBaseActivity. Normally my Activities extend AppCompatActivity.

Is this going to be a problem at all? Does OrmLiteBaseActivity extend AppCompatActivity anywhere? Or do I have to sacrifice AppCompat if I go with ORMLite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with ORMLite however I wouldn't recommend dropping AppCompat in favor of ORMLite. So what can you do?

By looking at the source of [ORMLiteBaseActivity](https://github.com/j256/ormlite-android/blob/master/src/main/java/com/j256/ormlite/android/apptools/OrmLiteBaseActivity.java) you can see that this class extends `Activity` and not `AppCompatActivity` which basically makes sense for a library. Furthermore you can see that the class doesn't do much.

So Option #1 don't use the ORMLiteBaseActivity or Option #2 create an own Base Activity for your app which extends `AppCompatActivity` and does the same as the ORMLiteBaseActivity. In other words: It would be an option to copy the class in your project and to simply replace the `extends` part.

Answer (score 0):

As for 2021, actually, you can do better. So you should not sacrifice AppCompatActivity for OrmLiteBaseActivity, you may use them both.

First, import OpenHelperManager:

```
import com.j256.ormlite.android.apptools.OpenHelperManager;
```

define object in your activity

```
private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = null;
```

use following getHelperMethod

```
private DatabaseHelper getHelper() {
    if (databaseHelper == null) {
        databaseHelper = OpenHelperManager.getHelper(this, DatabaseHelper.class);
        // we don't need  the following line that much
        // databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase(); // explicitly calls onCreate method of DatabaseHelper 
        //where you create tables for example, again it will be called anyway
    }
    return databaseHelper;
}
```

Override OnDestroy of your AppCompatActivity to free resources when your activity is done

```
 @Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (databaseHelper != null) {
        OpenHelperManager.releaseHelper();
        databaseHelper = null;
    }
}
```

So you may call any method of DatabaseHelper in my case listAllEntries() from your activity like this:

```
getHelper().listAllEntries();
```